# Issue when writing a list into a binary file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a `list` into a binary file and later load it again. I have this code:

```
with open('W.bin', mode='wb') as file:                                 
    file.write(bytearray(model.estimator.intercepts_))
file.close()
```

Where `model.estimator.intercepts_` is a list. However, I get this error:

```
  File "LM.py", line 200, in model_training
    file.write(bytearray(model.estimator.intercepts_))
TypeError: an integer or string of size 1 is required
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code? Thank you

Comment: You have an empty value you're trying to write

Comment: What are the contents of your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going wrong here.

First, your list must contain only characters (string of size 1) or integers in range 0 to 256 to use `bytearray`. Some element in your list does not satisfy that and you get a `TypeError`.

Second, you can only write a string to a file. If you need to write anything else, you should use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

with open('W.bin', mode='w') as file:                                 
    pickle.dump(your_array), file)
```

And then read by doing

```
with open('W.bin', mode='r') as file:                                 
    your_array = pickle.load(file)
```

Comment: May I have this little question. `mode='w'` is going to **overwrite** the existing file, correct?

Comment: It does, you can read about the different modes for open in here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Although if you use pickle it would not really make sense to append to the file.